# Digital clock not displaying

Tags: c#, winforms, clock

This is really confusing me.

All im trying to do is create a digital clock on a windows form, so i googled and tried this code but it refuses to show in the label.

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for all the help in advance

Comment: And how you configured your Timer?

Comment: Did you add a timer control to your form, or just paste in that in?

Comment: So the example i saw is wrong then? the guy said this is all the code you need.

Comment: @TimothyGoodes - you also need a timer to call this method every so often.

Comment: I do have a timer on my winform.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [`timer1.Interval`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.interval.aspx) to a reasonable value, like 1000.

You also need to set [`timer1.Enabled = true;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.enabled.aspx)

Finally you need to make sure your event handler `timer1_Tick` is connected to the [`timer1.Tick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx) event of an existing timer.

Comment: I already changed the interval timing in the properties but even with timer.enabled the code doesnt show in the label. all i get is the labels text.

Comment: how will i know the event handler is connected to the event?

Comment: Check the events tab in the properties window when you have selected the timer in the forms designer. Or right click the `timer1_Tick` method and select "Find all References".

Comment: Or just double click on the timer in the designer and you will navigate to the tick event handler if existing and create a new handle if it does not exist.

Comment: Yes the two events are connected.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in the `timer1_Tick` method and see if you arrive there?

Comment: Ok the problem was i enabled the timer in the code but it didnt enable it in the properties. i checked that and now it works perfect. thanks for all the help