# VB.NET realtime clock in a textbox

Tags: vb.net, time, textbox, clock, form-load

How can I make it so that when I load the form a textbox will show me (dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss) format clock that is actually moving and is synced with the system?

I tried googling it but so far couldn't find anything that works. Most answers dealt with making labels into clocks but I figured it's the same with textboxes and tried doing what they said with no results. It shows me the time but it's just the time when the form loaded not an actual moving clock. I think most of the answers I found on google are dealing with older versions of VB that's why I can't get it to work.

P.S. I'm just learning coding so the simpler the code the better. Many step by step (like I'm 5) comments are appreciated as well. Thank You

Comment: Have a Timer that ticks every once in a while (at least once a second), and attach the code that sets the textbox's text to the timer's tick event rather than the form's load event.  The required changes to what you already have would be easier to explain in detail if we knew what you already have.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344288/digital-clock-not-displaying?rq=1

Comment: A textbox is a very strange choice, allowing the user to edit the time does not make sense.  A Label is of course the correct choice.

Comment: Oh ok I got it. I just missed the part where you have to add the Timer to the form

Comment: The textbox is set to read only. It's a textbox for visual purposes really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Timer to your form, and add this code to it's tick event.

```
 Textbox1.text = Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

You now have a textbox which tells you the current date and time.
Don't forget to enable your timer, though!

Comment: also replace the "-" with a "/" if you want it to output as "yyyy/MM/dd"

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your time and date string inside a timer. this is how it looks like:

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

```
    TimerText.Text = TimeString
    DaterText.Text = DateString
```

End Sub

It will surely show you a moving/real time clock that was sync to your computer. :)